# AWS S3 file search using Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

We are using a java class to dowload a file from AWS s3 bucket with the following code

```
inputStream = AWSFileUtil.getInputStream(
            AWSConnectionUtil.getS3Object(null),
            "cdn.generalsentiment.com", filePath);
```

AWSFileUtil is a class which check the credentials and gets the inputstream from S3bucket using the getInputStream method.The filePath is the file inside cdn.generalsentiment.com bucket.

We want to write a method which can just check whether the particular file exists or not in the AWS S3 bucket and returns a boolean or some other value.

Please suggest me a solution for this.

```
public static boolean isValidFile(AmazonS3 s3,
        String bucketName,
        String path) throws AmazonClientException {
    try {
        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata =  
s3.getObjectMetadata("cdn.generalsentiment.com", path);
    } catch (NotFoundException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

If the file exists it returns true, else it throws NotFoundException, which i want to catch and return the "isValidFile" method result as false. 
Guys any other alternative for the method body or return type would be great.

The updated one

```
public static boolean doesFileExist(AmazonS3 s3,
        String bucketName,
        String path) throws AmazonClientException,
        AmazonServiceException {
    boolean isValidFile = true;
    try {
        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = 
s3.getObjectMetadata("cdn.generalsentiment.com", path);

    } catch (NotFoundException nfe) {
        isValidFile = false;
    }
   catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        isValidFile = false;
    }
    return isValidFile;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Daan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429242/45773) using [GET Bucket (List Objects)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) (via the respective wrapper from the [AWS for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/), see below) is the most efficient approach to get the desired information for many objects at once (+1), you'll need to post process the response accordingly of course.

This is done most easily via one of the respective methods of [Class AmazonS3Client](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html), e.g. [listObjects(String bucketName)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#listObjects%28java.lang.String%29):

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(); // provide credentials, if need be
ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
        .withBucketName("cdn.generalsentiment.com");
for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
    System.out.println(objectSummary.getKey());
}
```

#### Alternative

If you are only interested in a single object (file) at a time, using [HEAD Object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) will be much more efficient, insofar you can deduce existence straight from the respective HTTP response code (see [Error Responses for details](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html)), i.e. [404 Not Found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) for a response of *NoSuchKey - The specified key does not exist*.

Again, this is done most easily via [Class AmazonS3Client](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html), namely [getObjectMetadata(String bucketName, String key)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObjectMetadata%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), e.g.:

```
public static boolean isValidFile(AmazonS3 s3,
        String bucketName,
        String path) throws AmazonClientException, AmazonServiceException {
    boolean isValidFile = true;
    try {
        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = s3.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, path);
    } catch (AmazonS3Exception s3e) {
        if (s3e.getStatusCode() == 404) {
        // i.e. 404: NoSuchKey - The specified key does not exist
            isValidFile = false;
        }
        else {
            throw s3e;    // rethrow all S3 exceptions other than 404   
        }
    }

    return isValidFile;
}
```

Comment: Whoa, I never even knew you could get the HEAD Object separately from the actual object. That's definitely a more efficient approach to find out whether a single file exists in S3. +1 to you too!

Comment: Wow! this solves my worry..  Thank you guys a lot.                  Btw small exception handline case which i edited in my actual post, please walkme through to handle that exception

Comment: @SangramAnand: I've included and modified the function you provided to address your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you walkthrough Steffen...                                  Actually the class is not handling the NotFoundException, its going to a hibernate transaction class and then throwing exception their. I made some changes in code to fix the issue... please suggest me if the code is good.

Comment: @SangramAnand: I've fixed the code - S3 is actually not using dedicated exception types, rather only a generic [AmazonS3Exception](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/AmazonS3Exception.html); as I said, the code has been from the top of my head, sorry for being misleading - I've actually tested the code now and it works for me like so, good luck!

Comment: Are there any constants available in the SDK for error codes, specifically something like AmazonS3Client.NO_SUCH_KEY - just to make things a bit more readable.

Comment: @RTF - there are quite some generic ones, check out [Constant Field Values](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/constant-values.html) for example; also, you'll find several enumerations for things like the [EC2 instance types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/InstanceType.html) etc.

Comment: You may also want to check for 403. I see 403 when file does not exist, it may be due to the way security permissions are set.

Answer (score 2):

Use the GET Bucket S3 API:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

and specify the full file name as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

this is simple way to find existing folder in bucket. above answer also true.
       folder name contain '/' at last , 
            it return true .

note: mybucket/userProfileModule/abc.pdf, it my folder structrue

```
    boolean result1 = s3client.doesObjectExist("mybucket", "userProfileModule/");
    System.out.println(result);
```