# Spark :How to generate file path to read from s3 with scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, filesystems

How do I generate and load multiple s3 file path in scala so that I can use :

```
   sqlContext.read.json ("s3://..../*/*/*")
```

I know I can use wildcards to read multiple files but is there any way so that I can generate the path ? For example my fIle structure looks like this:
           BucketName/year/month/day/files

```
       s3://testBucket/2016/10/16/part00000
```

These files are all jsons. The issue is I need to load just spacific duration of files, for eg. Say 16 days then I need to loado files for start day ( oct 16) : oct 1 to 16.

With 28 day duration for same start day I would like to read  from Sep 18

Can some tell me any ways to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read multiple text files into a single RDD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029873/how-to-read-multiple-text-files-into-a-single-rdd)

Comment: The issue is to generate the file paths dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036343/5019163), You can specify whole `directories`, use `wildcards` and even `CSV of directories and wildcards`. E.g.:

```
sc.textFile("/my/dir1,/my/paths/part-00[0-5]*,/another/dir,/a/specific/file")
```

Or you can use **`AWS API`** to get the `list of files locations` and read those files using spark .

You can look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429640/5019163) to AWS S3 file search.

Comment: My issue is to how do I get the list of my keys in from start day how do I get the paths dynamically. All the paths . Start day - 28

Comment: All of getting from input is start day and end date. Is there any utility to generate the dates between them so that I can create a list by concatenation

Comment: I updated my question based on ur solution. Is that a right way to do this ?

Comment: Yoi have three starts at the end in the url . its will read all the files under 2016 folder

Answer (score 0):

You can generate comma separated path list:
sqlContext.read.json (s3://testBucket/2016/10/16/*,s3://testBucket/2016/10/15/*,...);